# make an update to backend database without changing password

Tags: node.js, onclick, axios, reducers, react-fullstack

I have an app in which users can track food trucks. On the user dashboard, users can update their location. Upon confirming the location update, the client sends a .put request to the backend. The problem is that the .put request is updating every value for the user account object(i.e. id, username, email, password AND location).

[image]

In the input that allows the user to change their location, the only value that is modified is location. However, I think there's a bug that changes the password as well. The password is stored as a hash value. Therefore, when the put request is made, I think the location update onClick is passing in the hashed value of the password for the user, which then changes the password in the database. When I try to login with a user that has just changed their location, I get an error back saying invalid credentials because of this. How can I solve this problem?:

Here is the action in question:

```
// edit location for diners
export const editLocation = (changes, id) => dispatch => {
    dispatch({ type: EDIT_LOCATION_START })
    axiosWithAuth()
        .put(`https://foodtrucktrackr.herokuapp.com/api/diner/${id}`, changes)
        .then(res => {
            console.log(res);
            dispatch({ type: EDIT_LOCATION_SUCCESS, payload: res.data })
        })
}
```

DinerDash.js (condensed to only the relevant lines):

```
const DinerDash = props => {

    const [locationEditMode, setLocationEditMode] = useState(false);

    const [updatedAccount, setUpdatedAccount] = useState({
        id: props.id,
        username: props.username,
        email: props.email,
        password: props.password,
        location: ''
    })

    const changeLocation = e => {
        console.log(updatedAccount);
        e.preventDefault();
        props.editLocation(updatedAccount, props.id);
        setLocationEditMode(false);
    }

    const handleLocationChange = e => {
        setUpdatedAccount({
            ...updatedAccount,
            location: e.target.value
        })
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <h1>This is the diner Dashboard component</h1>
            <h2>Welcome, {accountInfo.username}</h2>
            <p>
                Find trucks near: {props.location}
                <ArrowDropDownCircleIcon 
                    className="location-edit-icon" 
                    onClick={() => setLocationEditMode(!locationEditMode)}
                />
            </p>
            {locationEditMode && <div>
                <input placeholder="Enter a new location" onChange={handleLocationChange}/>
                <button onClick={changeLocation}>Done</button>
            </div>}
            <br />
            <button onClick={logout}>Logout</button>
        </div>
    )
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        id: state.account.id,
        username: state.account.username,
        email: state.account.email,
        password: state.account.password,
        location: state.account.location
    }
}
```

code from the reducer:

```
case EDIT_LOCATION_START:
            return {
                ...state,
                isLoading: true
            }
        case EDIT_LOCATION_SUCCESS:
            return {
                ...state,
                isLoading: false,
                account: {
                    id: action.payload.id,
                    username: action.payload.username,
                    email: action.payload.email,
                    password: action.payload.password,
                    location: action.payload.location
                }
```

code from the backend:

```
// how diners edit account
router.put('/:id', (req, res) => {
    const { id } = req.params;
    let updatedDiner = req.body;
    updatedDiner.id = id;
    const hash = bcrypt.hashSync(updatedDiner.password, 8);
    updatedDiner.password = hash;

    diners.editDiner(updatedDiner, id)
        .then(updated => {
            res.status(200).json(updated);
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
            res.status(500).json({ errorMessage: 'An error occured while updating account' });
        })
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to send an empty password , when there is no change in the password, keep a separate variable for password other than the default password key , In backend check if its not empty and then proceed.

Backend :

```
router.put('/:id', (req, res) => {
    const { id } = req.params;
    let updatedDiner = req.body;
    updatedDiner.id = id;
    if (updatedDiner.password){
         const hash = bcrypt.hashSync(updatedDiner.password, 8);
         updatedDiner.password = hash;
       }
    else
   {
         delete updatedDiner.password
    }

    diners.editDiner(updatedDiner, id)
        .then(updated => {
            res.status(200).json(updated);
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
            res.status(500).json({ errorMessage: 'An error occured while updating account' });
        })
})
```

Comment: Oh wow, didn't see your answer until now. I ended up solving this problem by creating a separate endpoint for changing diner location using a PATCH request. Since location is the only thing that needs to be changed, I can use a PATCH request and the password is not affected. Let me see if I can make this work using your way.